# How to best redirect customers to a login page? (ISP)

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking, isp

I'm trying to come up with the cleanest way to redirect a user to a logon/payment page from an ISP gateway router. We run a small ISP and would like to force users to have to log in prior to getting onto the internet after connecting.

I've seen this very frequently on hotel wireless, those 'pay for time' wireless accesspoints, etc.

This would run at the gateway level. We are using all CentOS Linux. I would like to give out IPs by DHCP on the network.

I have thought about doing it with iptables (I have done it before with FreeBSD and ipfw's fwd action -- but not with iptables) and DNS. iptables seems like the better option -- since it would be easy to programmatically create/remove rules without having to reload or restart any service. But coping with secure connections (SSL) is problematic -- users would get certificate warnings when being redirected to the logon page.

Has anyone done something like this? Any experience or knowledge would be very much appreciated.

Apologies if I have omitted anything or anything is unclear.

Comment: Wired or wireless?

Comment: Michael, a combination of wireless backhaul and client CPE is used - but this isn't really visible to the gateway (everything is delivered as CPE mac address)

Comment: And have you looked at existing systems like PacketFence?

Comment: How did you eventually solve this? Care to share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to deal with certificate warnings requires some control over the clients:

You create your own CA and deploy the CA cert to the clients in their trusted CA root certificate stores.

You then create a signed certificate for signup.example.local and the aliases `*.*` and `*.*.*`  which is against all best practices but works well enough in specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for commercial use, I suggest buy a certificate for *.yourdomain.com (it costs about $200 IIRC). I trust you already have a webserver that redirects http to https and implements an [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) policy. People get frustrated when they see those certificate warnings on their browsers.